# Get unix script to behave as if it was run from a different folder

Tags: shell, unix

I am using a scheduler to run a unix script which starts up my application. The script is in the PATH of the user used by the scheduler. Hence, can be run from an y

My application log files are created relative to where the script is run from. Unfortunatley, the scheduler does not run the script from the folder I had hoped hence log files are not going to correct folder.

Is there any way in I get the script to run and behaves as it was run from a specified folder, e.g. `./ScriptName.sh Working_Folder | Run_Folder`

Note: I cannot change the script

Answer (score 2):

if your scheduler run your tasks using a shell (which it probably do) you can use `{ cd /log/dir ; script; }` directly as command.

if not, you need to use a wrapper script as stated by @Gilles but i would do:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /log/dir
exec /path/to/script "$@"
```

to save a little memory. The extra exec will make sure only the script interpreter is in memory instead of both (sh and the script interpreter).

Comment: you need a trailing semi-colon within `{ braces; }`

Answer (score 1):

If you can't change the script, you'll have to make the scheduler run a different command, not the script directly. For example, make the scheduler run a simple wrapper script.

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /desired/directory/for/log/files
/path/to/script "$@"
```

Comment: You may also wish to check that the target directory exists and is writable.